# цикл while(-1 or -1) не завершается

Tags: python

```
s = 143*'687'
while s.find('68') or s.find('7777'):
    s = s.replace('68', '7', 1);
    s = s.replace('7777', '7', 1);
print(s)
```

В дебагере видно, что получается строка `7`, но цикл не завершается. А почему? Какие критерии для while, чтобы завершиться? В условии должен получится только 0? и как тогда подправить мой цикл?

Comment: `bool(-1) === True`

Comment: подправить подумал так: `while s.find('68') != -1  or s.find('7777') != -1:`

Comment: `while ('68' in s or '7777' in s)`

Comment: @entithat все понял! но насчет оператора 'in' хотел спросить. Например `if('68' in s)`, то он буквально спрашивает "есть ли подстрока `68` в строке `s`, если да выдать `true`, если нет `false`"? или в случае `true` он выдает найденную подстроку?

Comment: @entithat и еще получается из `bool(-1) === True` следует, что любое число кроме 0 это `True`? (и естественно строчных переменных)

Comment: методом ПРОБ И ОШИБОК выяснил что выражение `'68' in s` сугубо булевое

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод проб и ошибок

```
'sad'.find('1')
# > -1
```

`while` работает, пока значение равно `True`

`True` в питоне - это все что не `False` (логично) - то есть все что не:

- `None`
- `0`
- `''`
- `[]` (`list()`)
- `{}` (`dict()`)
- `set()`
- `False`
- и тд

То есть чтобы ваш цикл завершился, нужно условие

`s.find('68') > -1 or s.find('7777') > -1` (или `!=`)